# MVC Auto-Submit form if data on URI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC application I have a search page that will display a few data-entry boxes and a "submit" button to execute the search... All this is fine and dandy and works as expected.

However, I need to implement a "deep-link" search mechanism where the data-entry fields are pre-populated from the URI string and then execute the search.

How can I get the Controller's `Index` method to show the main view and then execute the `Search` method to fill the `<div id="results">` of the view.

### Index.cshtml

```
@model Models.SearchRequest

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    .
    .
    . Data entry boxes for search
    .
    .

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>


    <div id="results">
        <!-- Results of search go her -->
    </div>
}
```

### SearchController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index([FromUri] Models.SearchRequest request)
{
    .. validation of the request

    return View(request);
}

public ActionResult Search(Models.SearchRequest request)
{
    ViewModels.ResultsVM results =  ... stuff that executes the search ...

    return PartialView("ResultsPV", results);
}
```

### ResultsPV.cshtml

```
@model ViewModels.ResultsVM
.
.
.  Lots of Razor to display the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just solved the problem.

-1 In my `SearchRequest` model, I added

```
public ViewModels.ResultsVM Result;
```

-2 Changed the the `Index` method to add

```
if (...uri data is valid...)
{
    request.Result = ExecuteSearch(request);
}
```

-3 Changed the `Search` method to

```
return PartialView("ResultsPV", ExecuteSearch(request));
```

-4 Extracted all the code that actually did the searching into a new method

```
private ViewModel.ResultsVM ExecuteSearch(Models.SearchRequest request)
{
    ViewModels.ResultsVM results =  /* stuff that executes the search */

    return (results);
}
```

-5. Changed the `<div id="results">` to ...

```
<div id="results">
    @if (Model.Result != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("ResultsPV", Model.Result)
    }
</div>
```